# Check to see if the script has already run before on a particular machine?

Tags: vbscript

So I have the following scipt that I run when a user logs off using the logoff script section in Group Policy (I would like to run a check to see if it has already run before on the particular computer.  If it has run before I would like the script to exit.  If it hasn't then I want it to run the script and mark itself as "already been run".  How can I do that?):

```
strComputer = "." Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colInstalledPrinters =  objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Printer Where Network = TRUE")

For Each objPrinter in colInstalledPrinters
    objPrinter.Delete_ Next
```

Comment: What's wrong with simply running it twice? After all, it does not do anything bad if you run it a second time…

Comment: It deletes all the network printers.  Then I have GPP that adds a bunch of printers at logon.  I don't want the users to have to reselect their default printer everytime.  There is NO need to remove the printers more than once.  We are moving offices and have all new printers so I only need to remove the printers one time per machine.

Comment: Well, then simply write a lock file (or some registry entry) as the last step of the script and check for that as the first step. When it's there, you've run the script already and can exit right away.

Comment: Can you write an example of that?  I've tried a couple things and they don't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  Here's the revised script:

```
Option Explicit

Dim oShell,strComputer,objWMIService,colInstalledPrinters,objPPrinter

Private Function KeyExists (keyName)
    Dim bKey

    On Error Resume Next

    bKey = oShell.RegRead(keyName)

    If TypeName (bKey) = "Empty" Then
        KeyExists = False
    Else
        KeyExists = True
    End If
End Function



Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

If keyExists("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\CRusse\RemovePrinters") Then
    wscript.quit
Else 

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colInstalledPrinters =  objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Printer Where Network = TRUE")

For Each objPrinter in colInstalledPrinters
    objPrinter.Delete_
Next
    oshell.RegWrite "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\CRusse\RemovePrinters", 1, "REG_SZ"
End If

Set oShell = Nothing
```